# In React, how to change the height of a <div> based on the length of innerHtml displayed on browser?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is specific to React.
Let us say there is  containing html text, including boldness etc.
In React, I am trying to change its height if the innerHtml is too long, saying "exceeds 5 lines". 
Where should I change the height? componentDidMount? Or componentWillUpdate? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @FrontEnd HL, basically, if you don't set a div height, the div will have a div height "auto" by default. So, you increase the content inside the div, it will increase its height automatically since you lock its width.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The height of a container adapts to it's content by default and i can't imagine a case where you would need to do something like this. Can you describe your specific use case?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the official docs if you wish to touch the DOM you've to do it in the componentDidMount event.

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering.